# Question mark instead of class name in Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse CDT I have a C++ method defined as:

```
CUfunction getKernel(CUmodule& module, const std::string& name);
```

it uses `CUfunction` and `CUmodule` that are defined in `cuda.h` which is correctly imported.

However when Eclipse tries to compile this, I get an error on this method:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? getKernel(? &, const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)
'
```

Does it mean that for some reason it cannot find `CUfunction` and `CUmodule` classes?
However in the same source file I use them without any complaint by Eclipse...

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: need 15 characters: g++

Comment: I've never seen g++ doing `?` in its output. Are you looking at Eclipse's tooltip?

Comment: @T.C. yes, it is the tooltip, I tested now running cmake from the command line and there it works. so it must be something in the Eclipse configuration.

Comment: My best guess is that the indexer doesn't know CUfunction and CUmodule. Perhaps you should add paths to files where they are included explicitly? (search for preprocessor in the project settings)

Comment: @PaulOmta that's it! thanks, I looked at the indexer options, I doubled the file size limits and reran the indexer, error gone! Please write this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get question marks if the indexer doesn't know your types.

You can search for unresolved include files with the menu option: Project -> C/C++ Index -> Search for Unresolved Includes. (Eclipse Luna)

Folders of files that show up in that search can be added in the project settings under: C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Entries tab, CDT User Setting Entries (may need to be enabled in the Providers tab). Note that there are separate settings for each programming language.